# Using Affine Transformation to expand polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, coordinate-system, affine-transformation

I have a shape file, and I'd like to grow each feature by 13.7% or 14%. The program crashes every-time I try to use affine transformation.

Any recommendations? I don't have a license for ARCgis.

Link to the shapefile is here
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/frys1pur7g1mts1/ZlfKXM-Go6

Answer (score 3):

You didn't give any details about the crash. I've repeated the same process using your shapefile, the `Affine Transformations 1.0.0` plugin with QGIS 2.2.0, and everything was ok (after a five minutes waiting time).

I must tell you that, during the transformation, if you see the `Not responding` message, this doesn't means the software stopped to work. Few days ago I had to wait more than two hours for an affine transformation for a half of a million features. So, if this is your case, my advice for you is to wait for the process to finish.

In the images below you can see some images from the normal transformation process. If you did not wait enough it is possible to take this as a crash:

[image]

[image]

But, here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Sorin! Thank you! You're right, it stopped responding every time. I guess I need more patience. Cheers.

Comment: Here's the magnified shapefile:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/magnify_1_14/us_res_only_2010_magnified_1_14.ZIP

Comment: How about scaling from the center of each feature?